# Continuous Imperative

Tags: infinitives, continuous

Is it correct to say?

"Be doing it at the moment I come in."

Example:

> This is very important to me. Please, when I call you at 3 pm tomorrow, **be reading** my letters so that she can see you in the middle of the process of reading my letter at the exact same time I call you.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at [the topics that are covered here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions that ask "is this right or wrong" need to make it clear *what part* of the words or sentences are concerning. You have added a clarifying comment under an answer, but please use the "edit" link above to edit the original question to have all the information.

Comment: @AndyBonner when I put all the questions in the oridinal post, I'm told that there are too many questions, so you left me no choice :)

Comment: Yes, please ask one question at a time on Stack Exchange, and don't use comments to carry on a discussion that asks new questions. There's no harm in posting once about continuous tense in imperatives and again about the other examples, or editing this question so that the focus is "What is the best way to [say what I want to say]?"

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say _I want you/would like you to be reading my letter..._

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's rare, but perfectly grammatical, and the scenario you describe is when it is mostly likely to be used.

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to clarify. Is there the same thing with perfect and perfect continuous? Have done it **by 5 pm** tomorrow! 
Have been doing it **for at least three hours by 3 pm** tomorrow!

Comment: I can't fault these grammatically, but I can't imagine anybody saying them. Also, the first one is likely to get confused with the idiomatic phrase _have done with it_, meaning something like "give it no further attention".

Comment: Are there any other ways to convey the desired meaning? **by 5 pm tomorrow** and **for at least three hours by 3 pm tomorrow** ?

Comment: Not as a direct imperative. People would say _I expect you to have..._ or _You must have..._, or if they really want an imperative _Arrange that you will have..._ or _Be sure that you have..._.